# Rails 3 Subtotaling

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm still a newbie with Rails (and actually development period).  I'm using Rails 3.

activity has these fields: id, user_id, activity_type (integer).

In my view, I want to show a count of each activity type the user has done, something like this:

```
 <%= activity.activity_type %> - [count for activity]
```

Only, I can figure out how to do it.  In my controller, I tried different things like:

```
@user = current_user

@activity_type_ids = Activity.select("DISTINCT(activity_type_id)")
@activity_type_counts = Activity.where('user_id = ? and activity_type_id = ?', @user.id, @activity_type_ids).count
```

or

```
@activity_type_counts = Activity.where('user_id = ? and activity_type_id = ?', @user.id, @activity_type_ids).group("activity_type_id").count
```

In my view, I've tried:

```
<% @activity_type_counts.each do |activity_type_count| %>
  <%= "(#{activity_type_count.activity_type_id}) #{activity_type_count}" %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<% @activity_type_ids.each do |activity_type_id| %>
  <%= "(#{activity_type_id.activity_type_id}) #{@activity_type_count}" %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

---

**updated with models and controller**
fixing the model details

I have three models: user, location and activity.  A user has many locations.  A location can have many activities.

user.rb

```
has_many :locations
```

location.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :activities
```

activities.rb

```
belongs_to :location
```

activity_report_controller

```
@user = current_user
@locations = @user.locations
@activities = @locations.activities.count(:group => "activity_type_id")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have

```
class User
  has_many :activities
end
```

Then you can just say

```
@user.activities.count(:group => "activity_type_id")
```

This should return an `OrderedHash` with the keys as the `id`s and the values as the counts.

---

UPDATE: turns out the original question was wrong, there is an intermediary `Location`

What you want is a has many through on user to activities

```
class User
  has_many :locations 
  has_many :activities, :through => :locations
end

class Location
  has_many :activities
end
```

Now in your controller.

```
@user = current_user
@activity_counts = @user.activities.count(:group => "activity_type_id")
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  For some reason when I do that, I get the error undefined method `activities' for #<Class:0x28ff3740>.  I double checked and user (has_many :activities) and activities (belong_to :users).  Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: How did you load the `@user` variable? It isn't actually a `User` object. (else the error would say "undefined method 'activities' for #<User id:12>", or something like that.)

Comment: Sorry Matthew.  I thought that if I only mentioned two models, it would be easier to describe.  There's actually three models - user, location, activity.  I updated my description above with the models and the controller.  I apologize for that.

Comment: it works! can i ask one more stupid q?  i'm trying to get each count to appear on a different line, so i tried (which doesn't work - there's an @ before each activity in my code):                                <% activities.each do |key,value| %>
  <%= activities.key %> <%= activities.value %><br />
<% end %>, but                                                    <%= activities.keys %> <%= activities.values %> works

Comment: `<% activities.each do |activity_id, count| %> <p><%= activity_id %> <%= count %></p> <% end %>`

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me to help me Matthew.